# How to generate a signed apk in the eclipse and want to know about keystore how it can be genrate what is the format of it

Tags: android

I am facing problem to generate a apk in the eclipse please help me how to generate it while using the eclipse i am facing the problem to generate a signed apk for google play store there should be a specific to the developer

I want to know about the keystore how its work and how its generate a personalised apk for developer

Comment: more details would be highly appreciated and would help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your project -> Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package

Answer (score 0):

step 1:create or generate new key store password,use if existing password u have.
step 2:export your project -> Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package.
step 3: give your key store password.